# Control setLocation offset by 4px on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, position, swt

I've noticed an issue with the function `Control#setLocation(int, int)`. I use it to synchronize the movement between two `Shell`s, i.e. if I move the first one, the second is moved by the same amount of pixels.

That all works fine, except for one small thing: The actual position of the `Shell` after calling `setLocation()` is offset by 4 pixels (on Windows 7, didn't get the change to test it on another OS).

Here is a sample program that illustrates the problem:

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, true));

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Label: " + i);

        final Shell otherShell = new Shell(shell);
        otherShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        new Button(otherShell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button");

        Listener synchronizeMovement = new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                Rectangle parentBounds = shell.getBounds();
                Rectangle displayBounds = Display.getDefault().getBounds();
                Point size = otherShell.getSize();

                /* Check if there's sufficient space to the right of the parent */
                if ((displayBounds.width - (parentBounds.width + parentBounds.x)) >= size.x)
                {
                    otherShell.setLocation(parentBounds.x + parentBounds.width, parentBounds.y);
                    System.out.println(parentBounds + " -> (" + (parentBounds.x + parentBounds.width) + ", " + parentBounds.y + ")");
                }
            }
        };

        shell.addListener(SWT.Move, synchronizeMovement);
        otherShell.addListener(SWT.Show, synchronizeMovement);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        otherShell.pack();
        otherShell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

If I position the main window in such a way, that the output is

> Rectangle {124, 100, 276, 143} -> (400, 100)

I get the following result after measuring manually:

[image]

Which leads me to the conclusion that there is an offset/border/margin/whatever involved that I'm not aware of.

The desired outcome would be that calling `setLocation(400, 100)` results in the `Shell` being located at "(400, 100)" and not at "(396, 96)" (which should be a reasonable assumption, right?).

Does anyone have detailed insight as to why this is the case and how to fix it?

---

**Update**

If I use `SWT.NO_TRIM` as the style of the `otherShell` it works just fine. So it has to have something to do with the window decoration (frame).

Comment: For what it is worth this works correctly on Mac OS X

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, that's good to know. I'll try it on linux when I get home.

Comment: Does SWT have a getInsets() function like AWT?  getInsets() returns the border size of a Frame in AWT.  Maybe SWT has a similar function.

Comment: @PeterQuiring Not that I know of... The thing is, that 4px isn't the height/width of the whole frame/border.

Comment: Works fine on Linux as well (a bit on the laggy side though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Reading the documentation of `Shell` I found this:

```
public Shell(Shell parent)
```

> Constructs a new instance of this class given only its parent. It is created with style **`SWT.DIALOG_TRIM`**.

`SWT.DIALOG_TRIM` (which is `SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER`) on Windows seems to add this extra padding/margin/border around the `Shell`.

This small example illustrates the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

    Shell childOne = new Shell(shell);
    childOne.pack();
    childOne.open();
    childOne.setBounds(0, 100, 100, 100);

    Shell childTwo = new Shell(SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
    childTwo.pack();
    childTwo.open();
    childTwo.setBounds(0, 200, 100, 100);

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Which makes it obvious that `SWT.DIALOG_TRIM` is responsible...

In my case I solved it by specifying the style explicitly:

```
new Shell(shell, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
```

---

**tl;dr**

If you want to position your `Shell` pixel-perfect, don't use `SWT.DIALOG_TRIM`, but rather `SWT.SHELL_TRIM` or don't create your `Shell` as child of another `Shell` at all.